# Couldn't websites that want to track our activity just store the data in the DOM?

Tags: privacy, cookies, html, html-5

For example as the value of an attribute of a html tag.

```
<div cookie='id=1234'></div>
```

Then if the user deletes the cookies while at least one page of the website is open, a javascript script would regenerate the cookie by reading the DOM.

Do you know of any websites that are doing this already?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, I don't know any website that is doing this. Simply, because it's a silly idea. The DOM is in the memory, and when you access it you're accessing objects stored in the memory. If a website wants to do this, it would simply store the cookie in a JavaScript variable.

```
var Cookie = 'COOKIE_VALUE';
```

But there are much much better ways of creating sticky cookies. A good example is the [evercookie](http://samy.pl/evercookie/).

Comment: aren't websites cached? that would give a slightly greater expiration to 'DOM-stored tracking information' than just memory.